# wpf- green border with tick icon for correct textbox using Validation.HasError or another way

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, textbox, validationrule

I have a Textbox that bind to a validation rule.
I am able to display red border when Validation.HasError is True

However, I am not able to display green border when user input is correct and I found that because my Trigger property replys on **Validation.HasError** and **Validation.HasError** IS NOT False when there is no validation error.

I wonder if there is a proper way or workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the default Border to be Green, change it in Trigger, when `Validation.HasError` is true.

Using [msdn exapmle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753962(v=vs.110).aspx), you can set `BorderBrush` and `BorderThickness` in the Style:

```
  <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="TextBox.Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Other parts of the code are

```
   <TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" Height="30" FontSize="15" DataContext="{Binding}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
         Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
         Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Age"
             UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

and

```
public class AgeRangeRule : ValidationRule
{
    private int _min;
    private int _max;

    public AgeRangeRule()
    {
    }

    public int Min
    {
        get { return _min; }
        set { _min = value; }
    }

    public int Max
    {
        get { return _max; }
        set { _max = value; }
    }


    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int age = 0;

        try
        {
            if (((string)value).Length > 0)
                age = Int32.Parse((String)value);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Illegal characters or " + e.Message);
        }

        if ((age < Min) || (age > Max))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false,
              "Please enter an age in the range: " + Min + " - " + Max + ".");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way I could avoid green as default?
since I want normal textbox when it is empty

Comment: Add another Trigger to the Style to consider more cases. See my edit.

Comment: Note that in this example, you should use Nullable int (int?) for the Age property.

Comment: thank you for your time.
I notice there was 
<local:AgeRangeRule Min="21" Max="130"/>

I wonder if this is like setting the property on the AgeRangeRule  Class?

I try the simlar approve to my own costume Validation Class and somehow I got the error: the property Min was not found in type "MyCustumeValidator"

Comment: I can help more if you update the question with your code. However, make sure these two are public with get and set accessors.

Comment: thank you Ramin.
Sorry I should try rebuild again. it works now after rebuild.